# How can I have two windows drives `C:` and `D:` within GitHub Actions in windows?

Tags: windows, github, filesystems, github-actions

I want to execute an automated test within a GitHub Action using `runs-on: windows-latest` and for that test I need to have two different usable devices, for example `C:` and `D:`. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Since the windows-latest image is likely to *not* have a drive `D:\`, check if your GitHub Action script can use the [windows command `subst`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/subst) (as in "[How to map a local folder to a drive letter in Windows](https://www.computerworld.com/article/2694895/how-to-map-a-local-folder-to-a-drive-letter-in-windows.html)")

```
subst D: C:\Folder\Example
```

That way, you get your `C:\` *and* your `D:\` drives.